# Como alterar o valor de um Array que esta dentro de um $

Tags: php, javascript

Não tenho muita ideia de como usar array, muito menos envolver php nele, por isso peguei esse codigo da internet e consegui fazer algumas alterações que achei necessarias para enquadrar bem no site que estou desenvolvendo para um projeto escolar. Alterei muita coisa com excessão a essa parte do codigo, na qual ela adiciona items a um carrinho (Faz isso perfeitamente) mas quando eu tento adicionar o mesmo item uma segunda vez, ao inves dele somar as quantidades ele apenas emite um alert dizendo que o item ja foi adicionado.

Ja vi muitos tutoriais de como alterar os valores de um array, mas este em especifico esta dentro de um session, variavel $ e outras coisas que me confudiram um pouco.

Podem ajudar?

```
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
        if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
            $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
            if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
                $count      = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                $item_array = [
                    'item_id'       => $_GET["id"],
                    'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                    'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
                ];
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            } else {
                echo '<script>alert("Item ja adicionado")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="foodlist.php"</script>';
            }
```

Edit1: 
Não sei se é necessário, mas na mesma pagina tem mais esse codigo array.

```
    else
      {
        $item_array                   = array(
            'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
      }
  }
if (isset($_GET["action"]))
  {
    if ($_GET["action"] == "delete")
      {
        foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
          {
            if ($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
              {
                unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
                echo '<script>window.location="foodlist.php"</script>';
              }
          }
      }

  }
```

Comment: Pessoalmente acho que é irresponsabilidade se dispor a fazer um programa de e-commerce(ou qualquer outra aplicação visando o mercado) sem saber programar. Não quero participar desse código. Como a pergunta não está clara e apresenta amplos erros conceituais eu voto para fechar.

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta para fins didáticos, mas concordo com a visão do Augusto;

Comment: Desculpa, não especifiquei mas o site não é para fins de vender um produto e sim para um projeto de escola mesmo, ainda estou cursando um curso técnico.

Comment: Se é então o caso, coloque na pergunta que é um projeto escolar, pois na terceira linha você afirma que está desenvolvendo um site **`...no site que estou desenvolvendo..`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
        if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
            $count      = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            $item_array = [
                'item_id'       => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name'     => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'item_price'    => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
            ];
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        } else {
            //echo '<script>alert("Item ja adicionado")</script>';
            //echo '<script>window.location="foodlist.php"</script>';
            $key = array_search($_GET["id"], $item_array_id);
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["item_quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
        }
```

Comment: Deu o erro  Undefined offset: 0 e Undefined index: item_quantity na linha 30 (Que seria a do += $_POST)

Comment: Perdão, tinha esquecido de substituir uma variável. Confira agora.